# Azure Function's log streams from Azure Event Hub can't be consumed by Filebeat

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-functions, filebeat

Our team wants to import the log of Azure Function by Azure Event Hub and Filebeat into Elastic Search. We followed [this references](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-azure.html) to set up an Event Hub for Azure function. But we faced an issue with the wrong format of the log stream.

Firstly, Let me show what's the correct format we expect. Take Azure PostgresSQL's log from Event Hub for example:

```
[
  {
    "records": [
      {
        "time": "2023-01-04T03:45:31.1040000Z",
        "properties": {
          "timestamp": "2023-01-04 03:45:31.104 UTC",
          "processId": 8909,
          "errorLevel": "LOG",
          "sqlerrcode": "00000",
          "message": "2023-01-04 03:45:31 UTC-63b4f65b.22cd-LOG:  connection received: host=<host> port=<port>"
        },
        "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/<my subscription id>/RESOURCEGROUPS/<my resource group>/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DBFORPOSTGRESQL/FLEXIBLESERVERS/<postgres server>",
        "category": "PostgreSQLLogs",
        "operationName": "LogEvent"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Notice that the `properties` is a flattened json so that it can be consumed by Filebeat. We want this kind of `properties`. But the Azure Function's log looks like the following, which is a string rather than flattened json:

```
[
  {
    "records": [
      {
        "level": "Informational",
        "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/<my subscription id>/RESOURCEGROUPS/<my resource group>/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.WEB/SITES/<my azure function>"
        "operationName": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log",
        "category": "FunctionAppLogs",
        "time": "01/04/2023 01:55:00",
        "properties": "{'appName':'<my azure function>','roleInstance':'<id>','message':'Host Status: {\\n  \\'id\\': \\'<function app id>\\',\\n  \\'state\\': \\'Running\\',\\n  \\'version\\': \\'4.13.0.0\\',\\n  \\'versionDetails\\': \\'4.13.0+da9a765ed67be48c79440526f78fa1b5c6efdeea\\',\\n  \\'platformVersion\\': \\'99.0.10.764\\',\\n  \\'instanceId\\': \\'<instance id>\\',\\n  \\'computerName\\': \\'<computer name>\\',\\n  \\'processUptime\\': 69254486,\\n  \\'functionAppContentEditingState\\': \\'Unknown\\'\\n}','category':'Host.Controllers.Host','hostVersion':'4.13.0.0','hostInstanceId':'<host id>','level':'Information','levelId':2,'processId':1}",
        "EventStampType": "Stamp",
        "EventPrimaryStampName": "waws-prod-ty1-081",
        "EventStampName": "waws-prod-ty1-081",
        "Host": "<host name>",
        "EventIpAddress": "<ip address>"
      },
```

The string value of `properties` can't be processed by `decode_json_fields` of Filebeat either because the format is not json (the format is `'key': value` rather than `"key": value`). Is there any way to correct the format of `properties` before it is consumed by Filebeat? By the way, our Azure Function is deployed using a container.